# Add Session to URL in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

I am wanting to create a session in an URL and assign its value from a database.

For example i currently have URL creating a list according to the select statement.

I am wanting to include Favourite_ID but assign it to a session instead.

So something like: `Session ["Fav"] = Favourite_ID;`

***ASP.***

```
<asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" ShowFooter="False" ShowHeader="False" Width="460px" CellPadding="1" Height="193px">
<ItemStyle Font-Bold="False" Font-Italic="False" Font-Overline="False" Font-Strikeout="False" Font-Underline="False" />
<ItemTemplate>
    <table class="auto-style2">
        <tr>
            <ul>
            <td class="auto-style3">
                <h6><li><asp:HyperLink Runat ="server" NavigateUrl ='<%#"RecipePage?id=" + DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Recipe_ID").ToString()%>' ID="Hyperlink1"><%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Recipe_Name")%></asp:HyperLink></asp></li></h6>
            </td>
            </ul>
        </tr>
    </table>
</ItemTemplate>
```

***C#***

```
private void loadRecipe()
        {

            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0; AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Donald\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\DesktopApplication\DesktopApplication\Student_CB.mdf ;Integrated Security=True");
            con.Open();
            try
            {
                //Fetching top recipe     
                string query = ("SELECT * FROM Recipe LEFT JOIN Favourite on Recipe.Recipe_ID = Favourite.Recipe_ID WHERE Favourite.Student_ID = '"+UserID.Text+"' ORDER BY Recipe_Name");
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(query, con);
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                da.Fill(ds);
                DataList1.DataSource = ds;
                DataList1.DataBind();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

                //catch exception here

            }

            con.Close();
        }
```

Also im just testing what i can do at the moment. So excuse the bad practise of not using a parameter and using Try-catch.

This will change once i understand whether i can use a session the way im hoping to.

Comment: Are you saying that you want to include a value from the session in the URL that is generated?  It is unclear what you are trying to do here.

Answer (score 0):

I have used changed my current code to allow the use of a CommandArgument. In which calls and creates a session.

```
<asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" ShowFooter="False" ShowHeader="False" Width="460px" CellPadding="1" Height="193px">
<ItemStyle Font-Bold="False" Font-Italic="False" Font-Overline="False" Font-Strikeout="False" Font-Underline="False" />
<ItemTemplate>
    <table class="auto-style2">
        <tr>
            <ul>
            <td class="auto-style3">

               <h6><li><asp:LinkButton runat="server" OnCommand="Call_Fav" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Favourite_ID") %>' ID="bob" Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Recipe_Name")%>' /></li></h6>

            </td>
            </ul>
        </tr>
    </table>
</ItemTemplate>
```